# Task Queue- PHP

Tags: php

how to make a "Task Queue" using PHP?
I know how to store and create the queue.
The problem is in making it executed on Server-side without hanging the users session.
I have no permission to use the server. I only upload my files on it.

Answer (score 1):

I would have suggested using **crontab** if you had server access.

What I'd probably do is create another script that when called via HTTP processes say, 10 items. Then call this script on a regular basis yourself, or better, from another server where you can setup a cronjob.

However, if you're talking about having this work done straight after the users HTTP request, then in PHP you can use **ignore_user_abort()**. There are **[multiple examples on the PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)** you can use.